# How to display the contents of a global [static] variable in a textbox?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, textbox

I am setting up a form that displays calculated string variables.  The data comes from subs that put their results in a variable accessible by other procedures.  How do I define the textbox.controlsource property to display intermediate results and the continue with the process?

I have researched various help files in Access and could not find the answer.

```
Main module
Option Compare Database
option Explicit

--------

Public strAnswer As String

--------


Public Sub GetQuestion([Several arguments defining question])

--------[Process arguments and come up with an answer string]


strAnswer = [computed string from above]


End Sub


public Sub ShowAnswer


Docmd.Openform "AnswerForm",acNormal,,,acFormReadOnly,acWindowNormal


End Sub
```

The textbox control in answerform is either blank or #Name

How do I define the controlsource for the textbox?

Comment: If there is only one single variable to display, you could also use OpenArgs, `Docmd.Openform ..., OpenArgs:=strAnswer`

Answer (score 0):

Define a getter function, and use that to display the variable.

Define the getter:

```
Public Function GetAnswer() As String
    GetAnswer = strAnswer
End Function
```

Then, as the control source for the textbox, use `=GetAnswer()` to display the answer.

Note that you might consider making this object-oriented (defining a class and making `Answer` a property of the class) to avoid weird behaviour if the answer changes to that of a subsequent question. Your current design only works well for a single Q&A.